# Unable to install Xamarin on both Visual Studio 2012, 2015 (Windows 7 64 bit)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, xamarin

I have tried to install today Xamarin on Visual Studio 2012 it failed and tried to install on Visual Studio 2015 one month back it failed. There are some similar issues reported in stackoverflow, but looks like the installer was updated already and hence reporting new issue. Please help me to resolve this.

```
Installation of 'Android SDK' failed with more than one exception (attempt 3)
    Errors while installing items.
    Exception type: System.AggregateException
    Failed to install Android archive.
    Exception type: Xamarin.Web.Installer.InstallException
    Full stack trace:
    at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.AndroidSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32 tryNumber)
    at WindowsInstaller.ProgressPage.InstallationWorker()
    Failed to install Android archive.
    Exception type: Xamarin.Web.Installer.InstallException
    Full stack trace:
    at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.AndroidSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32 tryNumber)
    at WindowsInstaller.ProgressPage.InstallationWorker()
    Failed to install Android archive.
    Exception type: Xamarin.Web.Installer.InstallException
    Full stack trace:
    at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.AndroidSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32 tryNumber)
    at WindowsInstaller.ProgressPage.InstallationWorker()
```

Last few lines log file;

```
[2017-01-03 05:34:06.671] [Error] Attempting to clean up.
[2017-01-03 05:34:06.686] [Error] Trying to remove directory '<USER_HOME>\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-23\google_apis\x86'
[2017-01-03 05:34:07.685] [Warning] Attempt to delete a non-existing directory '<USER_HOME>\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-23\google_apis\x86.old96145954'
[2017-01-03 05:34:07.685] [Info] Status: failed.
[2017-01-03 05:34:07.685] [Error] Android SDK Platform API level 23, ABI x86, tag google_apis system image.
[2017-01-03 05:34:07.700] [Exception] Installation of Android SDK component 'system-image-23-x86-google' failed with exception.
[2017-01-03 05:34:07.700] [Exception] System.InvalidOperationException: Component installation failed
[2017-01-03 05:34:07.700] [Exception] at Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.AndroidComponentSystemImage.Install(String archivePath, String androidSdkRoot)
[2017-01-03 05:34:07.700] [Exception] at Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.AndroidSDKInstaller.InstallComponent(AndroidComponentBase component, AndroidSdkInstance instance)
[2017-01-03 05:34:07.700] [Info] Status: failed.
[2017-01-03 05:34:07.700] [Info] Status: failed.
[2017-01-03 05:34:07.716] [Exception] Installation of software item 'Android SDK' failed with exception.
[2017-01-03 05:34:07.716] [Exception] Xamarin.Web.Installer.InstallException: Failed to install Android archive. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Component installation failed
[2017-01-03 05:34:07.716] [Exception] at Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.AndroidComponentSystemImage.Install(String archivePath, String androidSdkRoot)
[2017-01-03 05:34:07.716] [Exception] at Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.AndroidSDKInstaller.InstallComponent(AndroidComponentBase component, AndroidSdkInstance instance)
[2017-01-03 05:34:07.716] [Exception] at Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.AndroidSDKInstaller.InstallComponents[T](List`1 components, AndroidSdkInstance instance, String progressMessageFormat, Object[] args)
[2017-01-03 05:34:07.716] [Exception] at Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.AndroidSDKInstaller.InstallSystemImage(List`1 components, AndroidSdkInstance instance, String apiLevel, SystemImageSpec sis)
[2017-01-03 05:34:07.716] [Exception] at Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.AndroidSDKInstaller.Install(AndroidSdkInstance instance, InstallationSet installationSet)
[2017-01-03 05:34:07.716] [Exception] at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.AndroidSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32 tryNumber)
[2017-01-03 05:34:07.716] [Exception] --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[2017-01-03 05:34:07.716] [Exception] at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.AndroidSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32 tryNumber)
[2017-01-03 05:34:07.716] [Exception] at WindowsInstaller.ProgressPage.InstallationWorker()
[2017-01-03 05:34:07.716] [Info] Status: failed.
[2017-01-03 05:34:07.825] [Debug] Showing manual installation window because of error
[2017-01-03 05:34:12.850] [Debug] Starting installation complete task.
[2017-01-03 05:34:12.850] [Info] Background installation worker completed.
[2017-01-03 05:34:13.193] [Info] Installation completed with failure
[2017-01-03 05:34:13.193] [Info] Status: failed.
```

Comment: May I know the reason for down vote..

Comment: This isnt really a development question. Granted its a tools question but some folks don't seem to like questions that aren't specifically asking about code.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you don't need Android Studio, just Android SDK. Secondly, preinstalling Android SDK doesn't help, since VS installer won't notice that and install its own copy, maybe even in a different location.

Suggestions:

1. Unistall Android Studio and Android SDK
2. Remove *\Program Files(x86)\Android* folder
3. Check security permissions for all folders and subfolders in your HOME folder. You should have Full Access.
4. Run VS Installer in Repair mode. If it doesn't help, unistall Xamarin and all related stuff (Android, IOS, etc) and reinstall

Answer (score 0):

Well obviously the Android SDK is failing to install.
The Android SDK is actually a separate install you can download and preinstall before your try to do the Xamarin install.

Just make sure to take the default path in the android SDK install so the Xamarin Install can find it.

URL to Android SDK:
https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads

If Android SDK and potentially Android Studio Install cleanly then come back and try Xamarin again.

Comment: Thanks, Android studio got installed. Tried to install Xamarin, failed again. It is eating my hard disk like anything 4 GB free space in C drive became 0 bytes free ********* [2017-01-03 09:18:50.188] [Exception] System.InvalidOperationException: Component installation failed
[2017-01-03 09:18:50.188] [Exception] at Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.AndroidComponentSystemImage.Install(String archivePath, String androidSdkRoot)
[2017-01-03 09:18:50.188] [Exception] at Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.AndroidSDKInstaller.InstallComponent(AndroidComponentBase component, AndroidSdkInstance instance)

Comment: oh yaeh the android SDK takes some SERIOUS space. Given the version and all the simulators etc Im not at all surprised to hear it ate 4gb and wanted more